# How to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to make `SocialSecurityNumber` key for `person` table. `[Key]` works but value for this key is generated by database,I want my given value to be persisted in database so I used 
`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`. Now when I try to `Add()` data I am getting this error.

[image]

So how can I set IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON by using Code First ,Fluent API or Annotations?

Following is my model class.

```
  public class Person
        {
            [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
            public int SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: Offtopic but don't store SSNs as integers unless you want to deal with, among other things, a whole lot of leading zero issues.

Comment: Is this an existing database or did you use Code First to generate it?

Comment: @Dismissile no existing database, used code first to generate

Comment: Did you generate the database once without the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None option and then you changed your code? Did you generate a new database after changing the code? Did you use migrations to change it? Can you confirm in your database that the SocialSecurityNumber field is not longer set to be an identity (I'm guessing it still is an identity)

Comment: Yes I did use Migrations. And did everything you mentioned. SocialSecurityNumber field is an identity. @Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. As in comments @Tim asked if I had used migration. In fact this was the step I did not do in next try. I just added another class and did NOT set it to `[KEY]` rather used full annotation `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`, I did not had to used migrations and this worked. As previously problem was being caused by `SocialSecurityNumber` being `identity` but now using this approach its no longer `identity` and hence IDENTITY_INSERT(which is still of OFF) does not apply to this. And I can change values.
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=278643422321981&set=a.118955391624119.1073741827.100005289761090&type=1&theater